# what is the mean of "static Int32 LVM_FIRST = 4096"

Tags: c#

I try to get content  of `listview`, but I can't understand this sentence;

```
static Int32 LVM_FIRST = 4096;
```

What is the mean of this? why is 4096?

```
static Int32 LVM_FIRST = 4096;
static Int32 LVM_DELETEITEM = (LVM_FIRST + 8);
static Int32 LVM_SORTITEMS = (LVM_FIRST + 48);
```

And the code link is http://www.4byte.cn/question/463761/get-items-from-windows-task-manager-process-list-c.html

Answer (score 2):

That is the windows message to be sent to the window referenced by `hWnd` in the win32 api call:

```
  Int32 apiSendMessage(Int32 hWnd, Int32 wMsg, Int32 wParam, string lParam);
```

YOU call it as follows:

```
 apiSendMessage(lhWndMyWindow, LVM_DELETEITEM,0,"0");

OR

apiSendMessage(lhWndMyWindow, 5003,0,"0");
```

The constant is just  user friendly way of codifying the message to send to the window. The last two parameters usually will contain pointers to detail data based on the message being sent.

Also, it looks like they are aligning the constants in some pattern for (L)ist(V)iew(Message)_XXXX calls